# Stack Overflow logo used on another site

Tags: support

Is the site at http://validateemailaddress.org/ affiliated with SO, or did they just steal the logo?

---

Logo from the above link:

[image]

Comment: How do we know SO didn't steal from them?

Comment: @Paran0a I am pretty sure the logo came from a competition and was designed by an SO member.

Comment: [My low budget Stack Overflow logo](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ca2-vpLUcAER4m2.jpg).

Comment: I don't think [so] owns any copyright over [paper stack icons](http://www.freepik.com/free-icon/overflowing-stacked-papers-tray_732488.htm#term=stacked%20paper&page=1&position=14) on their own. I'm pretty sure the SO logo includes the text also - which hasn't been stolen.  If I'm wrong, I'd expect a stern letter to be sent to Maroun Maroun sometime soon...

Comment: @Paran0a your username is splendidly relevant:)

Comment: @MarounMaroun did you paint the black box directly on your desk?

Comment: Validate email addresses or collect actual email addresses? What a great idea!

Comment: The angle of the lowest two "papers" isn't the same as on the SO logo; doesn't look like an actual straight copy.

Comment: And the paper curve lines up with the V - gotta give them some credit.

Comment: @Nyerguds It's a pretty exact match for the [old logo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266726/why-has-the-stack-overflow-icon-changed) though, where the top item in the stack has become part of the V.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I don't think so. The gap on the right between the first and second lines is bigger on the SO logo I think

Comment: @DavidG I suspect it's the latter. They reported a non-existent email address as being valid. All they seemed to have done is check that the MX record for the domain name exists.

Comment: @hinneLinks That's a tape! `:P`

Comment: I can see that the paper stack "cleverly" blends in with the 'V' in 'Validate'... however I'm really struggling to come up with a single design or user-facing reason for using that icon with that treatment. What is the metaphor? Do they expect users to have overwhelming lists of addresses to validate or something? Even though the icons are not identical (look closely, then look more closely... they are very similar but not identical in many ways), it does still seem very blatent. Feels very much like they are just riding the brand recognition of SO...

Comment: @CalvT I found a bigger version of the old logo.  Here they are [side by side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DsLVD.png).  They line up exactly (or as exactly as my eyes can tell when I use the cross-your-eyes-to-line-stuff-up-on-top-of-each-other method of viewing 3d pictures).

Comment: I'm pretty sure no one's going to confuse the two. And if they do, well, there's one less crappy question coming into SO! :)

Comment: I am confused. I went to validate my email and I ended up at "Stack Overflow"?? Can you help me with my email?

Comment: @Sayse What am I missing? How does the fact that someone has uploaded a nearly identical, possibly plagiaristic icon to some other website disprove copyrightability of SO's icon? One can dispute whether "paper stack icons" overall can be copyrighted, but the distinctive overflowing shape and solid/monochromatic design are a lot harder to argue against. In which case, if I were SO, I'd be considering petitioning that site and any others to remove such icons. But YMMV...

Comment: Speaking of [low-budget logos](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/81167/36398)...

Comment: @underscore_d - it isn't stack overflows icon. It is something they use as a component of their logo (note: I'm not a lawyer. I write code)

Comment: @Sayse Are you implying that SO took it from flaticon or any other supposedly public-domain site?

Comment: @underscore_d - no, as previously stated, it came from a competition. I'm saying I don't think you can copyright a shape. (again, I am not a lawyer)

Comment: @Sayse It's hardly the kind of vague shape that comes around by chance. It's a defining component of the logo, so it's subject to copyright claims. Try ripping off some aggressive corporation like Nike's even simpler logo, and then let me know whether your opinions on copyright have changed.

Comment: To explain the rationale behind the logo, this is the validation algorithm used by Validateemailaddress.org: `bool ValidateEmail (std::string& address) { return ValidateEmail(address); }`.

Comment: Based on the fact that the letters in the name are so close together I assume that this logo was not created by a StackOverflow designer.

Comment: IANAL, but I play one on the Internet :-).  Although there is a potential copyright issue here, it looks like there might be more fertile ground for a ***trademark*** case (supposing SO has trademarked its logo).  The basic question there is whether the ValidateEmailAddress.org logo could create confusion for ordinary people about the relationship between that site and SE (owner of the supposed trademark).  As far as I am concerned, it certainly could, and for me it *would*, had I not seen this discussion.

Comment: @LuisMendo - yeah, that logo is *waaaaay* wrong. It should use a fixed-pitch font. :-)

Comment: In my opinion it is violation, and if there was any money spent marking the SO logo then money should be spent enforcing it.

Comment: The fact that someone (the OP) is confused about whether that site is affiliated with SO demonstrates pretty clearly that that site is trying to make themselves appear more legitimate by stealing SO's logo. This should be pursued.

Comment: @Sayse Exactly. It's not like the creator of the SO probably had the icon in a vision and invented it from scratch. These things always develop iteratively from some earlier source. Undoubtedly SO's icon creator basically forked it from somewhere else and them made a custom tweak. What was it that Steve Jobs liked to say? Great artists steal?

Comment: Someone needs to tell them they need a catchier domain name...wouldn't find me typing that into a browser to validate an e-mail address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow Logo stolen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366542/stack-overflow-logo-stolen)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Since this is tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), and a few people are commenting that it doesn't appear to be entirely the same as the Stack Overflow logo, I just wanted to point out the similarity to the [*old* logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266726/why-has-the-stack-overflow-icon-changed):

[image]

Here they are resized and placed side by side:

[image]

And to make it really obvious:

[image]

On closer inspection, and it may just be my eyes, but I *think* you can also make out where they've extended the bar upwards to form the V - it appears to be every so slightly narrower than the original bar:

[image]

Comment: +1 for gif. Makes it so much more obvious.

Comment: @Avenoir That was pushing my mspaint skills to the limit...!

Comment: I thought there was a slight chance for it to just be coincidence, but your gif really solidifies that it was probably stolen.

Comment: I think it's more likely that they legally downloaded [this image](http://www.freepik.com/free-icon/overflowing-stacked-papers-tray_732488.htm#term=stacked%20paper&page=1&position=14) (perhaps without realizing the connection) and then used it to create their company logo.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah - although they don't line up perfectly in the gif, bear in mind I was resizing stuff by eye in paint, not the best of editors... I think that probably accounts for any slight differences

Comment: @JDB Editing it to remove the rounded corners to make it match exactly, by coincidence?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Yeah, maybe not that exact one, but there are [plenty of icon libraries](http://fontawesome.io/icon/stack-overflow/) that include an SO-inspired image.

Comment: @JDB All of which are therefore legally questionable

Comment: Only if the overflowing papers icon is trademarked by itself. Haven't seen any evidence yet that SO owns that trademark. (Maybe they do... just haven't seen it yet.)

Comment: @JDB The trademark itself is (almost) irrelevant to this discussion.  Whether it's trademarked or not doesn't remove copyright of this specific design.

Comment: I think the main question (asked by the OP) was whether or not stealing that icon would cause brand confusion, which, as best I understand, not being a lawyer, is an issue around trademarking, not copyright. Granted, SO probably owns the copyright. Of course, I'm just a developer, so this is all quite above my head.

Comment: Copyright: clearly violated, trademark: maybe. Ok then. Release the sharks! erm.. I mean lawyers!

Comment: @noah1989 I guess that's a call for SO themselves - for one, do they actually own the copyright on the original logo - I assume it was their original work, but I don't know for sure.  Secondly, depends how aggressive they want to be on it I guess!  Note that my answer doesn't really answer your question either - it was just intended to address the few comments to show it matched the old logo!

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I think this answers my question. The logo was copied, not just the same by coincidence or from a common source, which I found interesting. Maybe the developer for the site was looking up something on SO when the manager came in and said: Oh, that looks great! Now make the top thing blend into the V and we are done!

Comment: @JamesThorpe paint not the best of editors? paint is the **only** editor dammit.

Comment: @MacroMan I have a colleague that would agree with you there :)

Comment: Great answer. It's pretty obvious they have taken the logo and used it for their own design. Thing is though, the logo *(on it's own)* is all over the web and as [@Maroun point's out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327007/692942) the [Stack Overflow logo](http://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) includes the "stack overflow text". So I'm not sure this is trademark / copyright issue.

Comment: @Lankymart Note that [the logos page](http://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) lists separate icons too.  I don't know if the old design was listed this way, but it's reasonable to assume it was.  Either way, the [trademark guidelines page](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) says: _"Any content on the Stack Exchange Network not contributed by users is copyrighted. "_  Even if the trademark is the whole image, the image itself is copyrighted.  Removing part of it (the text) and overlaying your own text doesn't change that.

Comment: @JamesThorpe [The More You Know ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_More_You_Know)...

Comment: Yea but theirs has a blue bg. Seriously, it's obviously at least "highly inspired" by SO, but no one would confuse them with SO and given the simplicity of the design (which was probably heavily inspired by some other, earlier source) I don't think there's any reason for us to "hate" on them.

Answer (score 4):

The **new** [Stack Overflow logo](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) includes the "stack overflow" text:

[image: Stack Overflow logo]

The [ValidateEmailAddress](http://validateemailaddress.org/) looks different, and mainly amateur.

From the [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> Use of Our Name or Logo in Advertising
> **Do not** use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by
> Stack Exchange Inc.
> **Do not** use our name or logo in a way that might
> imply a false sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.
> **Do not** use any name or logo that is similar to or might be confused
> with our name or logo.
> **Do not** distort or alter our logo in any way. 
> **Do not** use our logo in a way that confuses our brand with another brand.

I think that none of the above are violated; no one will ever confuse the two logos, nor will they think about an affiliation with Stack Overflow.

Furthermore, if you pay more attention, you'll note many differences in angles, gaps, number of "papers" inside the stack and more. So I don't think it's considered stealing.

---

Tip for future users: To avoid unpleasant and embarrassing situations, create a low budget logo so everyone will have mercy on you. Here's mine:

[image]

Comment: Compare side-by-side with the [old logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DsLVD.png) though.  That's a lot more questionable.

Comment: maybe it's purposely not really the same logo but near enough to confuse the user. IMO if i see the icon showed by the OP i think immediately to SO, not something different.

Comment: @maroun https://www.spreadshirt.com/stack-overflow-robots-kids-shirts-A8517588 isn't this violating copy right conditions? it is quite similar :)

Comment: That logo is very provocative, but I still don't think they're close enough (or worth) to require removing this one.

Comment: funny enough the SO favicon looks the same :p, at least by being so small it's quite hard to tell a difference

Comment: This answer doesn't touch on copyright at all, which the icon itself *is* covered under. While trademark protects our name and prevents people identifying themselves as us, copyright protects the actual design. They *are* using our old logo. They've just slightly modified the last bar to look like a V.

Comment: "I think that none of the above are violated" ...... _really?_ Setting aside the unclear definition of 'use our logo' (is that meant to be literal?), this directly violates at least points 3 and particularly 4, since as James's answer has shown, their logo is a blatant alteration of SO's old one.

Comment: I'm talking about the new logo guys. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That would still hit point 3, though

Comment: @animuson So are you guys planning to ask them removing the logo?

Comment: Whatever you do, just don't contact them by e-mail...

Comment: You should've stopped after commenting...

Comment: `nor will they think about an affiliation with Stack Overflow.` this was actually, exactly one of the questions the OP asked, so I beg to differ - OP: `Is the site at http://validateemailaddress.org/ affiliated with SO`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I thought about that and decided to post an answer as well, no conflicts at all.

Comment: @darrensweeney Yupe, and that's why I answered.