# The Stack Overflow logo is being used on a different, unrelated website

Tags: discussion, logo

[This Austrian government website](http://www.ahs-vwa.at/) is using what looks like the Stack Overflow logo on the left side at the nav menu. This logo doesn't even seem to fit with the caption, which translates as "The Basics".

It's not like on [Stack Overflow's logo is being used in Clear Linux project's website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327793/3560202), where it is an exact copy, but it's still a really weird coincidence.

Maybe this is a widely-used symbol and it has just been adapted at two different locations, but I still wanted to make you aware of it.

Comment: After looking at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327014/3560202, it looks exactly like the old SO logo

Comment: Actually it is exactly like the linked question, since [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327991/215552) notes what's wrong with it. This site is also using Font Awesome.

Comment: This is a link to the icon they are using from Font Awesome. It is the stack-overflow icon from Font Awesome. http://fontawesome.io/icon/stack-overflow/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yup! `.vwafront .span4 a::before {font-family:FontAwesome;`

Comment: @Cody Gray Thanks for the edit, I'll keep this markup in mind.

Comment: Seems from the page content that they're using that icon to denote a box of documents. Maybe [fa-file-text](http://fontawesome.io/icon/file-text/) or [fa-file-text-o](http://fontawesome.io/icon/file-text-o/) would be an alternative they might like.

Comment: My problem is that fontawesome is using an old version of the Stack Overflow logo. How dare they.

Comment: @TinyGiant It’s probably an old version of Font Awesome, with the then-current Stack Overflow logo.

Comment: @JF How dare they? Get out your torches and pitforks everyone! I'll grab the tar and feathers.

Comment: I don't think it's a logo. I think it's an icon. Like a ❤