# Stack Overflow Logo stolen

Tags: discussion, status-completed, legal, logo

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LZDZR77](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZDZR77)

If you look at the fifth picture, you can clearly see the Stack Overflow Logo next to the text "Multiple Storages". It looks like somebody just Googled "orange storage stack icon" and took one of the first icons without asking for permission.

[image]

Comment: But ... it's not stolen, it's still there for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyyNz.png

Comment: Stolen may be a bit harsh, the Stack Overflow logo is part of some icon packs as a "social media icon". Really lazy "one of the first google hits" example: https://icons8.com/icon/3527/stack-overflow

Comment: Looked at the title, was horrified to learn that the logo might be missing on the main site. Wondered if someone had nicked it on a drunk night out, along with a beer glass and a traffic cone, and Stack Exchange would be offering a reward for its safe return.

Comment: Ironically, if you click the link and buy that product, Stack Overflow gets referral credit

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71sIP1gW1tL._SX522_.jpg

Comment: @Gimby pretty sure that's not an authorized use of the StackOverflow trademark

Comment: Please do not add any snarky reviews to the Amazon product page. Really. I'm serious. Don't do it.

Comment: Well, technically it's impossible to steal intellectual property or a digital product. You only can duplicate it, but if you do so, the original owner wouldn't become worse off. That's the inherent property of information.

Comment: hey, they stole the Q&A votes stuff too: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LZDZR77/?tag=stackoverflow17-20#customerReviews

Comment: Where we see a stack overflowing, they must see stuff being added to a container.

Comment: @ForceBru movie and TV piracy results in less money going to the creators and actors

Comment: @Gimby: that's a black-and-white version, not the specific SO color scheme version, right?

Comment: Ironically the stack overflow logo means there is not enough storage.

Comment: For you folks who are arguing about "theft" and whether or not IP can be stolen, this would most likely fall under Trademark law .... assuming that the icon is a registered trademark of the StackExchange organization.  Theft (or copyright violation) is not the issue.

Comment: @scmi I said "really lazy first google hit" for a reason, that is not the only example :) Point is not to condemn so quickly, they could have just carelessly ripped from a third party which is actually the one to accuse.

Comment: It's gone now :)

Comment: Aaand.. [its gone](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xZ_JiU7L9Zk/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: yay...Found back!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

As per https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance, you should send an email to team@stackexchange.com

> If you ever stumble across anything that looks like it violates our copyright, trademark, or policies, please let us know.

Comment: Hope this is not side business of stack over flow . :p

Comment: @MuhammadYasir Maybe that's why question quality has dropped: they're too busy with their bag making business to focus on keeping the bad questions out.

Comment: @MuhammadYasir - If this is (as I suspect) a trademark issue, then it is necessary to defend your trademarks to prevent them falling into common use.  Generally speaking, protecting a trademark is not a source of income.

Comment: @StephenC I think he Yasir means making bags.

Comment: It also says *The Stack Exchange name and logos are trademarks of Stack Exchange Inc. The names and logos for sites and products operating on the Stack Exchange network are also trademarks of Stack Exchange Inc.*

Comment: Oh.  I thought he meant pursuing people for IP violations.  There are poeple who do that you know.  Google the phrases "copyright troll" and "patent troll".

Comment: @MuhammadYasir market is tough. standing with single website don't  enough to put meat on your table. ;)

Answer (score 16):

It appears to have been removed now

[image]

Comment: Right. They fixed the images but what do the bags look like?

Comment: I don't see why they'd have this logo on them; it was just used as a pictural representation of the bag having "multiple storages"

Comment: its just the open example of how startup works :p

Comment: They told them this was being discussed on Meta. Nobody wants that hanging over their heads.